# Honda FIT GP5 vin number

Tags: honda, fit

How to find Honda FIT GP5 2014 vin number. I have search it in everywhere. But couldn't get a solution.

Comment: You have this car and you want _your_ VIN, or you just want a random VIN for that model car from the internet?

Comment: I have this car. I need to find the VIN to submit to the owners.honda.com website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of places where you can find the vin number.

1. On the dash board, look through the windshield on the driver side bottom corner.
2. On the driver side rear door pillar right next to the driver seat.
3. On the insurance paper.
4. On the title for the vehicle.
5. Some newer cars on the fenders(on the inside difficult to see without pulling it) , hood, trunk(or bonnet), rear quarter panel where the rear door latches.

here is an image that can help you:

[image]

Comment: You can't just copy google image search links from your URL bar.  You get a long, messy link that may or may not work later.  Click on the image you want in the search results to see the full image, then right click the picture and "Copy Image Location" or similar.  Then use _that_ URL without all the Google cruft on it.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thanks for the tip will do that from next time, sorry for now.

Comment: No problem at all.  If you have any other questions, come visit us over [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop).

Comment: +1. I, to my shame, used to work building Hondas and this picture details very well all the places that the vin is put. I worked that section, and you get a full sheet of vin stickers that go all over the car, basically in every nook and cranny. Be careful though, they're very fragile and will be utterly destroyed if you mess with them in the slightest.

Comment: A door has a jamb, not a jam.  Door Jam sounds like a very bad-tasting thing to put on toast, or perhaps a large concert at which members of  tribute bands perform classic Doors hits together.

Answer (score 3):

To find the VIN number of your car:

When you are standing outside the car, facing it, the VIN number should be on a plate *under* the glass of the windshield near the lower right corner of the windshield.  This is the case for almost every modern car in the US.  I guess the VIN plate might be on the left side (facing the car) on a Right Hand drive model - not sure, but it should be under the windshield on one side or the other.

[image]

[image]

Another easy trick is to look at your car insurance card.  It will normally have the VIN number as well.